# Iframe session values aren't working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, iframe, safari

The application runs in the iframe, We have kept the all form values in session

- There is no login and no database for the iframe,
        If form having **back** button to change the pervious form data that    values are in session

But in the **safari web browser not able to get the session value**.

Anyone please, help to use **session with iframe in safari browser**.

Comment: Instead of posting this question over an over again, how about starting with the workarounds that can be found via a simple google search? **https://www.google.com/search?q=session+iframe+safari&hl=en**

Comment: @ndm i have tried that method is not work properly, any some other logic to   use instead session

Comment: If you've tried something, then you should mention that in your question, and explain why it's not working, so that people don't possibly waste their time explaining stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not allow cross-domain cookies. You load an iFrame with the contents and set a session in the iFrame, Safari will not save the session value. This problem also occurs in IE6/7 but can be resolved by sending a P3P header.

INTERNET EXPLORER:

header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"'); //ADD IN THIS LINE IN ORDER TO SOLVE THE INTERNET EXPLORER AND IFRAME GET SESSION VALUES

SAFARI:

In my opinion, When before start using iframe in safari browser, load the unwanted form in new pop up window keeps that form values set in session and close the pop window this process takes 2 to 3 seconds and then start using the iframe with session it's works fine to me.

Thank You,